# BigQuery returns 400 is dataset not found in query

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery returns 400 Bad Request if dataset is not created and a query references it.

```
  {
    "code" : 400,
    "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "location" : "query",
      "locationType" : "other",
      "message" : "Error preparing subsidiary query: Dataset deft-virtue-628:account_875 not found",
      "reason" : "invalidQuery"
    } ],
    "message" : "Error preparing subsidiary query: Dataset deft-virtue-628:account_875 not found"
  }
```

Ideally it should return 404 Not found, since the Dataset is not created. Is there a way to change this behavior.

**UPDATE:**

400 Bad Request is returned only in case of very complex queries where dataset/table is missing in inner queries/queries containing table wildcards.

For queries like this `"SELECT * FROM [no_dataset.no_table]"` 404 Not Found is returned.

The below query returns a 400 Bad Request

`SELECT * FROM (TABLE_QUERY(dataset_exists, 'table_id CONTAINS "not_exist"'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 404/notFound error should be returned when referencing a table that does not exist in a query.

Note that this is the case for most queries today. For example the query `select a from doesNotExist.doesNotExist` returns a 404/notFound for the table "doesNotExist.doesNotExist". However I do see some cases with more advanced query features that conflate this error with 400/invalidQuery.

I've logged a issue on our internal tracker to resolve this. Thanks for the bug report!